# MAT HPROF: No space left on device

Tags: android, eclipse, hprof, eclipse-memory-analyzer

I'm running my app on my phone, while debugging with MAT. After I try to dump the HPROF file in Eclipse, I get the error:

**Failed to save hprof data into temp file. No space left on device.**

I've done a google search on this already...empty. I'm wondering which device it's referring to. My phone? 
And no space left? Which memory would this be referring to?
Now, every time I try to dump an HPROF file, I get this error.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Yes, it's referring to your phone.

Comment: @gmale : ok. so any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Turns out this was because /tmp on my computer was 100% full. Deleted un-needed /tmp files, and it's fine now.